# If a column has a value (numeric or text) then show it's corresponding cells in another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 spreadsheets, in the first spreadsheet, in column E, if there is any value present ( whether numeric or text then show its corresponding cells ( i.e only name and ID) in another spreadsheet.

Sheet 1:

[image]

Desired Output in spreadsheet 2:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ideal output, you may try:

```
=filter({'Sheet 1'!D:D,'Sheet 1'!A:A ,'Sheet 1'!E:E},'Sheet 1'!E:E<>"")
```

Comment: Hi rockinfreakshow, I'm getting an error. Could you please explain me, what am I missing ? "FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 3946, column count: 1. Actual row count: 3947, column count: 1."

Comment: based on the error it could be that you are comparing mismatched sizes like `A1:A5`(5 columns) with `A2:A5`(4 columns)

Comment: This is the formula, =filter({Sheet1!O2:O,Sheet1!Q2:Q ,Sheet1!Z2:Z,Sheet1!AA2:AA,Sheet1!AB2:AB},Sheet1!E:E<>"")

Comment: make it `Sheet1!E2:E<>""`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

You need `FILTER()` function. Try-

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:D,Sheet1!D2:D<>"")
```

Or `QUERY()` function like-

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:D,"where D is not null",1)
```